# IntersectionObserver "standards" and element.scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, scroll, intersection-observer

It has been my experience that with Edge that the "target" received by your IntersectionObserver callback has been set to the newly scrolled-in element rather than (like Chrome and Firefox) where it still reflects the element that started scrolling-out. I played with smaller thresholds but sadly my function thinks the scroll snap fell short and don't bother changing the current image marker dot.

I'm looking at separate issues with Firefox as well :-(

Apart from waiting 'n' nanoseconds after a scroll event is there a better way to know where your carousel is at?

Guess I'll just take the "IF" out and see if I can fix FF.
EDIT: Firefox only seems to allow me to observe 2 elements for my intersection observer. Do I have to new-up a separate IntersectionObserver object for each element being observerved?

```
        carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
        let observerOptions = {
            root: carousel,
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
        };

        bannerObserver = new IntersectionObserver(imageScrolled, observerOptions);
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            bannerObserver.observe(document.getElementById("d" + i));
        }


    function imageScrolled(divContainers) {
        divContainers.some(function (imgContainer, containerIndex) {
            let targetDiv = imgContainer.target;
            if (imgContainer.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                if (targetDiv.dataset.imgId != currDot) {
                    clearTimeout(bannerLoop);
                    dots[currDot].style.backgroundColor = "";
                    currDot = targetDiv.dataset.imgId;
                    dots[currDot].style.backgroundColor = DOT_COLOR;
                    bannerLoop = setTimeout(scrollBanner, bannerInterval);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntersectionObserver is currently too unreliable/inconsistent so I went for a simple onscroll event: -

```
    function onTheMove(e) {
        for (let i=0; i < e.srcElement.children.length; i++) {
            if (e.srcElement.scrollLeft == e.srcElement.children[i].dataset.imgId * e.srcElement.children[i].clientWidth) {
                if (e.srcElement.children[i].dataset.imgId != currDot) {
                    clearTimeout(bannerLoop);
                    dots[currDot].style.backgroundColor = "";
                    currDot = e.srcElement.children[i].dataset.imgId;
                    dots[currDot].style.backgroundColor = DOT_COLOR;
                    bannerLoop = setTimeout(scrollBanner, bannerInterval);
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

caniuse.com is wrong on this one :-(